# jquery auto height fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have implemented jquery on the site (click the plus sign)
http://pligg.marsgibson.info

click the first two stories 
first story has a gap when expanding while 2nd story doesnot 
how to set auto height for this jquery

here is my style.css

http://pligg.marsgibson.info/templates/wistie/css/style.css

I am trying to edit the .toggle_container .block

Comment: You should only be including your scripts `<script src="/templates/wistie/js/jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/wistie/js/toggle.js"></script>` at the very end of your document; you are including them after every instance of `.stories`

Answer (score 1):

just remove the line `height: 80px;`

Comment: If I remove the height: 80px;
then jquery will not be smooth 
it expands to few px and then jumps 
see now (click the 2nd story) it jumps just when "readmore" appears

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a few [HMTL no-no's](http://validator.nu/?doc=http://pligg.marsgibson.info/). You can't have block-level elements within inline-level elements (`<p>` tags within `<span>` tags (you should replace `<span>` with `</div>`).

To fix your problem, replace

```
.toggle_container .block {
margin: 0px 10px 0px 75px;
padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px; /*--Padding of Container--*/
height:80px;
}
```

with (remove `height:80px`)

```
.toggle_container .block {
margin: 0px 10px 0px 75px;
padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px; /*--Padding of Container--*/
}
```

EDIT:

If you set the heights explicitly, I think it will animate better. Add this right after your as the first line of the inner function in the `.ready()` function:

```
jQuery(".toggle_container").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).height(jQuery(this).find(".block").height());
});
```

Comment: If I remove the height: 80px; then jquery will not be smooth it expands to few px and then jumps see now (click the 2nd story) it jumps just when "readmore" appears

Comment: This happens when the height of the element isn't set explicitly. I added something that I think will fix your problem. Let me know if that works.

Comment: It removed the "Read More" for more than one line summary
click the first and second story

Comment: Hmm, I just edited the jQuery I posted to make it check `.toggle_container .block` instead of `.toggle_container` for the desired height. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Doing this makes the jquery to function abnormally
its now not expanding